# getch python retornando sem usar

Tags: python, windows

Estou tentando usar o `getch` do python para pegar a tecla que o usuário apertou, mas sem eu apertar nada ela está retornando "`b'\xff'`", e se eu usar `ord(getch())`, ela retorna 255. Se poderem me ajudar agradeço.

```
from msvcrt 
import getch key = msvcrt.getch() 
print(getch()) 
if key == 0: 
    quit() 
elif key == 1: 
    print("Game inicado") 
else: 
    print('Opção invalida!')
```

Comment: Adiciona o seu codigo, pra podermos reproduzir o erro e te ajudar ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sua sintaxe está errada no começo:

Ao invés de:

```
from msvcrt 
import getch key = msvcrt.getch()
```

Deveria ser:

```
from msvcrt import getch
key = msvcrt.getch()
```

Além disso, esse pedaço é suspeito:

```
print(getch())
```

Acho que o que você queria era isso:

```
print(key)
```

E também, ao invés de `key == 0` e `key == 1`, você deveria usar `key == '0'` e `key == '1'`. Ou seja, você esqueceu de colocar as aspas.

Comment: O maior problema nem é especialmente este, mas sim, por que eu nem aperto nada e o getch ja retorna algo.